# How to create polygons layer from datasheet in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector-grid, data-source

I would like to create a polygon shp file from a large dataset. The header looks like this: "Name   MINx    MAXx    MINy    MAXy"
I expect the layer to look like a grid.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried the "create grid" which seems to be meant for something totally different. I then used add layer from text delimited. I could create a point layer from there but can use only 2 x/y out of the 4. The file I got with MINx MAXx MINy MAXy are bounding boxes I'd like to represent in one single layer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to create polygons from MINx, MAXx, MINy and MAXy values**

1. Import the dataset as a delimited text layer *without geometry* (as an attribute-only table).

   [image]
2. Write an expression that combines the MINx, MAXx, MINy and MAXy fields into a polygon.

   One method is using the `make_...` geometry functions. First use the `make_point()` function to combine the corner coordinates into points. Use `make_line()` to combine the points into a *closed* line. Use `make_polygon()` to convert line into a polygon.

   It's very easy to make a mistake when combining the coordinates. I find it helps to make a quick sketch like this:

   [image]

   Pick any corner point, proceed counter-clockwise around the vertices, and finish by repeating the starting point.

   - MAXx MAXy (start)
   - MAXx MINy
   - MINx MINy
   - MINx MAXy
   - MAXx MAXy (end)

   The finished expression should look like this: `make_polygon(make_line(make_point(MAXx, MAXy), make_point(MAXx, MINy), make_point(MINx, MINy), make_point(MINx, MAXy), make_point(MAXx, MAXy)))`
3. Use the expression in the Geometry by expression tool to create the polygons. Be sure to copy the expression to the clipboard, so if you make a mistake you can edit the expression instead of re-writing it from scratch.

   [image]

Here's what the output looks like with my test dataset (I used the field calculator to add the geomWKT field):

[image]

Troubleshooting:

- If the polygons look like hourglasses instead of rectangles, the corners are out of order.
- If they're triangles, you either

  - skipped a corner, or
  - repeated a corner (there will be two vertices at one corner. You'll see a green X at that corner if you put the layer into edit mode and select a feature.